# Problems with creating a new Variable in Dataframe with mutate function

Tags: r, twitter, tidyverse, dplyr

To exclude all the tweets, which dont contain at least 4 words, i want to create a new variable via mutate funtion. "mysontweets" contains only the text variable of the dataframe "tweets_son.df"
I tried alot, but i doesnt work. Anyone up for some help? Obviously there is a problem with the inverted comma.

```
new_tweets_son.df <- tweets_son.df %>%  (mutate(tweets_son.df = str_detect(mysontweets, "([[:alpha:]]+[[:punct:]]*[[:space:]]+){4,}[[:alpha:]]+)"))
```

Comment: Can you write the output of `dput(head(df))` were `df` is your data frame?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringr::str_count` to count the number of words in a character string; so something along the lines of should work:

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    filter(str_count(mysontweets, pattern = " ") >= 4)
```

If you provide sample data, it's easier to give an example.

---

### Update

Example using some sample data I generate:

```
# Sample data
df <- cbind.data.frame(
    mysontweets = c("One two three", "a b c d e", "Start End")
);


df %>%
    filter(str_count(mysontweets, pattern = " ") >= 4)
#  mysontweets
#1   a b c d e
```